# Karate set token in local storage

Tags: karate

I can set some value in local storage with following script

- script("sessionStorage.setItem('foo', 'bar')")

But I need to set item passing a parameter.

For example,

save response token from a api call

- def token = response.token

Now I would like save this token to session storage. How this can be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Totally up to you to create some valid JS by string concatenation.

For example:

```
* def temp = "sessionStorage.setItem('foo', '" + response.token + "')"
* script(temp)
```

Also please read this section of the docs: https://github.com/intuit/karate/tree/master/karate-core#karate-vs-the-browser